# How to prevent user from entering spaces to rails text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application to render a form and take three inputs. I don't want the user to be able to enter spaces between characters. I am new to rails and am uncertain of where to go from here. Here is my form:

```
  <%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
    <p>
       <%= f.label :IP , "IP Address" ,  class: "input-lg"%><br>
       <%= f.text_field :IP , class: "form-control"%>
    </p>

    <p>
       <%= f.label :Email , class: "input-lg"%><br>
       <%= f.text_field :Email , class: "form-control"%>
    </p>
    <p>
       <%= f.label :Device , class: "input-lg"%><br>
       <p>
          <%= f.select :Device , [['Server'],['Network']] %>
       </p>
   </p>
   <p>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default"%>
   </p>
 <% end %>
```

I'm sure there is a way to do so with JavaScript or JQuery but I'm not very familiar with how to use JQuery in Rails or how I'd do this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do that at input time you'll need to use either Javascript or Jquery. I won't go over how to enable and debug that part just check some existing guides as there's plenty.

For the actual way of checking that, you'll want to:
- know when the user types something in one of the input fields you want to restrict;
- either prevent or replace the restricted inputs.

The easiest way of having it done is to bind a "keyup" event to the input fields you want to target, by passing the input selectors. In this case IP and Email.

```
       $("input[name='IP'], input[name='Email'").keyup(function(e) {
          var value = $(this).val(); 
    //read the value - jquery will pass the element that is triggering the event as -this- so you can get it by using $(this)
          value = value.replace(/\s+/g, ''); 
//replace all whitespaces by nothing, effectively removing them
          $(this).val(value); 
//assign the stripped of whitespace value to the val attribute of to the input field
        });
```

This can be made more complex to only accept particular patterns, only accept digits and etc, but the possibilities are endless almost.